# RoxyFilename Ckeditor change directory image

Tags: javascript, php, html, ckeditor

I tried to implement Roxyfileman with ckeditor. It worked. But when I tried to change the image default directory, it seemed not to work. 
Any idea?

Thanks you.

My config ckeditor ===> working well

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

//roxyFileman
    var roxyFileman = '/myapplication/boutique/admin/ext/RoxyFileman_143/index.html';
    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl='roxyFileman';
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl =roxyFileman+'?type=image';
    config.removeDialogTabs= 'link:upload;image:upload';
// end roxyFileman
};
```

the script for Roxyfilename : doesn't work

```
      <script>
          $(function(){
        FileSelected(file) {

          // Set the value of field sent to Fileman via URL param "field".
    //opener.document.getElementById(RoxyUtils.GetUrlParam('field')).value = file.fullPath;   
   opener.document.getElementById(RoxyUtils.GetUrlParam('home/workspace/myapplication/sources/')).value = file.fullPath;
          // Set the source of an image which id is sent to Fileman via URL param "img".
    //      opener.document.getElementById(RoxyUtils.GetUrlParam('img')).src = file.fullPath;
          opener.document.getElementById(RoxyUtils.GetUrlParam('image')).src = file.fullPath;
          // Close file manager if it's opened in separate window.
          self.close();
          // Close file manager if it's opened in JQuery dialog.
          $(opener.document).find('#dialog_element_id').dialog('close');

        }
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: You're going to have to actually explain what the problem is.  "Doesn't work" doesn't help anyone help you.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function FileSelected(file){
    window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(1, file.fullPath);
    self.close();
}
```

Learned from this post:
https://zerokspot.com/weblog/2009/09/09/custom-filebrowser-callbacks-ckeditor/

Answer (score 0):

There is conf.json file in roxyfileman root folder, and in this config file there is "SESSION_PATH_KEY": property you can give a value to this property like this "SESSION_PATH_KEY":    "roxy_path" AND in your code you can do

```
 $_SESSION['roxy_path']="your arbitrary directory";
```

then roxyfileman upload image to this directory you set.